# Using the asterisk (*) to specify width and precision in Go

Tags: go

The official *fmt* pacakge documentation at [golang.org](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) says this in respect to specifying width and precision -

> Either or both of the flags may be replaced with the character '*', causing their values to be obtained from the next operand, which must be of type int.

How will the asterisk (*) be used, say, for example, in the following scenario -

```
 var f float32 = 12.3456789
 fmt.Printf("%6.3f", f)
```

Comment: https://golang.org/src/fmt/fmt_test.go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be

```
var f float32 = 12.3456789
fmt.Printf("%*.*f", 20, 1, f)
```

See more at:

- https://github.com/golang/go/blob/8f4f1f63e9d5d171a669d0a9c4594bbaaf9ea6f7/src/fmt/fmt_test.go#L1590

Answer (score 3):

```
fmt.Sprintf("%[3]*.[2]*[1]f", 12.0, 2, 6)
```

equivalent to

```
fmt.Sprintf("%6.2f", 12.0)
```